# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried every solution found around on the internet, but I still get the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5
```

What could be the reason? I have checked all the implementation list is complete and with the right versions. I have checked also classpaths and everything else. But nothing works!!

**build.grande (Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ves.gennaio3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.grandle (Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup it looks like 16.0.4 is latest version

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4
```

Comment: Agreed. But gradle dependency checker shows "A newer version of com.google.firebase:firebase-core than 16.0.4 is available: 16.0.5"

Answer (score 3):

@Johns solution did not work for us as we ran into another known issue with that version (see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

What worked for us is to use the alias of firebase-core:

change `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4` to

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5
```